# Sum and sum of squares of digits -coprime

Tags: c++

> For the paragraph L, R
>    its sum of digits and the sum of its squares (in the decimal) is co- 
>    prime.
>    Count how many numbers in the paragraph L, R meet the above conditions

I was stuck on the sub21 
 exceeds time limit when R = 10^8 and Max R = 10^18:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class tinhtong 
{ 
    public: 
    long long getSum(long long n) 
    {  
    long long int sum = 0; 
    while (n != 0) 
    { 
     sum = sum + (n % 10); 
     n = n/10; 
    }  
 return sum; 
    } 
};

class binhphuong 
{ 
    public: 
    long long getpow(long long n) 
    {  
    long long poww = 0; 
    while (n != 0) 
    { 
     poww = poww + (n % 10)*(n % 10); 
     n = n/10; 
    }  
 return poww; 
    } 
};

int main()
{
    tinhtong g;
    binhphuong h;
    long long TONG=0,k,l,ucln;
    long long int m,n;
    cin>>n>>m;
    for(n;n<=m;n++)
        {
            ucln=0;
            k=g.getSum(n);
            l=h.getpow(n);
            while(k!=0 && l!=0)
                {
                    if(k>l)
                    k-=l;
                else
                    l-=k;
                }
            if(k==0)
                ucln=l;
            else 
                ucln=k;
        if (ucln==1) 
            TONG++;
        }
    cout<<TONG;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a code review question, which dos not really belong on this site, but I notice that you calculate `n % 10` three times, when once would suffice. Also, the modulus operator might be significantly faster than repeated subtraction.

Comment: Input the number as a string.  Convert the digit from text to number using: `number = string[i] - '0';`  This is faster than using division and remainder operations.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use classes to contain functions.  You can declare and define them outside of the class, as *free standing functions*.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you can calculate the sum and the sum of squares in one loop, avoiding multiple calls of same `%` operation.

Moreover, to calculate that two numbers are coprime, it is better to use the version of Euclide's algorithm that uses modulo instead of substractions. The code is below.

In this code, I use the fact that the sum of squares is greater or equal the sum.
I also use the fact that if the sum is a multiple of 2, it is also the case for the sum of squares.

If this code is not fast enough, you can try the suggestion in a comment to first convert the number to a string.

Another possibility would be the check if both numbers are multiple of 3 or 5, before calculating the GCD, as GCD calculation can be longer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

std::pair<long long, long long> getSum_pow(long long n) {
    long long int sum = 0; 
    long long int sumP = 0; 
    while (n != 0) {
        long long r = n%10;
        sum += r; 
        sumP += r*r; 
        n = n/10; 
    }  
    return {sumP, sum}; 
};

int main() {

    long long TONG = 0, a, b;
    long long int m, n;
    std::cin >> n >> m;

    for(; n <= m; n++) {
        std::tie (a, b) = getSum_pow(n);
        if (b%2 == 0) continue;
        while (b != 0) {
            a = a%b;
            std::swap (a, b);
        }
        if (a == 1) {
            TONG++;
        }
    }

    std::cout << TONG;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks all ♥ but with paragraph L R: 79066480162306286 331124487134727415 the program is faulty in timelimit

Comment: Do you know how much it is faulty?

Comment: I think there is some formula for R up to 10 caps 18

Comment: It is faulty at timelimit,with R = 10 ^ 8 then time = 1021: ((( .

Comment: 1021s instead of 1s ??